# C++ Destructor not working correctly, compile error, just trying to delete a member variable with destr

Tags: c++, destructor

Following class will be initiated with a member variable `newTodayTaskString` (`string`).

When destructing the object I like to delete the string but when compiling the project I get an error message pointing to the destructor delete line saying:

**delete: std::string cannot be converted to void**

Class:

```
class TodayTask {
private:   
    string newTodayTaskString;

public: 
    TodayTask (string t) : newTodayTaskString (t){}

    // Destr.
    ~TodayTask () {
        delete newTodayTaskString;
    }

    string getTodayTaskString () const {
        return newTodayTaskString;
    }
};
```

Comment: `delete` is not needed 99% of the time. C++ has automatic resource management, you don't need to destroy objects manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete` must be given a pointer, and can only be used to destroy objects created with `new`.

In this case, the object is a class member, and so will be destroyed automatically. You don't need to do anything with it in the destructor.

Answer (score 3):

In c++, memory can be allocated either automaticaly or manualy. 
If you define a simple variable, the memory for it is allocated automaticaly, in the [*Stack*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation). The memory is then automatically freed. For example:

```
void foo()
{
    std::string s;//memory is allocated here
}//the variable only lives inside the function, so at this point the memory is freed
```

The second way is to allocate the memory manualy, with the *operator new*, like this:

```
void foo()
{
    int * i = new int();//we allocate the memory for our variable here.
}
```

Here, the memory is alocated in the [*heap*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), and it will **not** be freed automaticaly in the end of the funciton, or anywhere else until your programm ends. 
In this case, you need to call *operator delete*, but you must call it **only once** for each variable:

```
void foo()
{
    int * i = new int();
    <...some code...>
    delete i;//we free the memory at this point.
}
```

Note that if you will try to delete the same variable twice, you might get a segmentation fault.

In your case you are trying to manualy delete a variable for which you have not manually allocated the memory, which leads to the error. In your case you don't need to bother with the destructor, everything will be done automaticaly.

Comment: good, but you don't mention the op's case: when there is a member variable in a class, so you're speaking about something similar but not exactly answer the question

Comment: @unkulunkulu, Yes, sorry, I pressed the posting button too early, and only then realized that it's only a part of the answer. Added the OP's case now, thx.

Comment: Sadly, double deletion doesn't guarantee a segmentation fault - that would make debugging far too easy. You get undefined behaviour. One quite likely outcome is to delete someone else's object, causing weird behaviour in a completely unrelated part of the program.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, true, changed "will" to "might". I think that you will only get segfault if the memory at that address was already allocated for some other program, am I right about that?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I think that most of your answer is irrelevant to the OP's question. If the class is allocated on the heap, the string will also be allocated on the heap. The answer is in the last 3 lines. Bottom line: `delete` accepts a pointer, and the OP is trying to delete member variable, not a pointer ==> compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `delete` only when you created it using `new`

Comment: the part about stack is not correct, if you call `new TodayTask`, then it is not on stack probably

Comment: I am taking about the code given by Marc in the context. Since new is not involved it is indeed created in stack

Comment: he didn't provide any context on how `TodayTask` is created, it could be not on stack

Comment: Sorry for lack of information, `TodayTask` will be created in the main and I do not use a pointer so we are on the stack. `TodayTask tt(newTodayTaskEntry);` so all the hints about new is correct. Since I do not use a pointer I cannot say delete. THANKS AGAIN for your great help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` is only needed when the object is created using `new`. In this case, your object is automatically created before the constructor since it is a member variable. Thus, it is automatically destroyed after the destructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

You don't 'delete' newTodayTaskString, since it hasn't been allocated with 'new'. It's a member variable -- it will be automatically constructed and destructed, there's nothing you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete `newTodayTaskString` as it is not you who allocates its memory

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have to delete the string. It's not dynamically allocated.

Just remember this:
use delete when you new something.
use delete[] when you new an array of something.